# A good timer for windows form game

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

A few days ago i started to do extrahomework. I wanted to create a game, in which you should avoid from random objects. Okay, i have all working game, but 
my method

```
private void Game_form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

    for ( int i =0; i < Bonus.Count; ++i) // Bonus - private list ( not more than 5)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bonus, Bonus[i].Object_Pos);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < Objects.Count; ++i) // Objects - private list ( not more than 10)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Kunai, Objects[i].Object_Pos);
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Main, player.Player_Pos); // Player ( only one )
}
```

and i have timer:

```
private void Drawing_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    Bonus_move(); // method for changing objects position in Bonus list 
    Player_move(); // method for changing player position
    Objects_move();  // method for changing objects position in Objects list
    Thread.Sleep(5);
    Invalidate();
    Thread.Sleep(5);    
}
```

Per 1 step i should change position on 7 px, when i change on 1 px - i guess my app has a good framerate ( by sight )
Right now timer has interval 11 ms and two Thread.Sleep(5) for a good framerate, but i have maybe from 15 to 30 fps, when i wanna at least static 30+fps.
 Could you reccomend me change something? Of course i understand that my code can be bad or something else.

Comment: if your code is working and you want someone to review it, then this is not the correct forum for it. I would recommend to post it on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Good luck

Comment: yeah, my fault. I have just visited this site 1 hour ago. Because my school teacher couldnt give some profit . I get it that i should use codereview, sry

Comment: Timer has a resolution of ~20-30ms. Setting Interval = 11ms is too optimistic. It is also only guarated to be no faster, not precise. And:  Any animation in winforms will be shaky, no matter which timer you use..

Comment: I saw info about multitimer for winforms, so, even using this timer will i have troubles?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suited to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)